# Adding class via [ngClass] to paragraph using 2-Way binding of Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, angular, two-way-binding

I have made 2 classes in home.css with names 'male' and 'female'. I have made 2 radio buttons with values as 'male' and 'female'. Now in my paragraph, I want to change background color of paragraph as I change the selection of radio buttons. I want to achieve this via [ngClass] in Angular 4.

**home.html**

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" [(ngModel)]="genderType">Male 
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" [(ngModel)]="genderType">Female 
<p [ngClass]="genderType">This is 3rd paragraph.</p>
```

**home.ts**

```
genderType: string = "male";
```

**home.css**

```
.male{background:green;}
.female{background:violet;}
```

Please, help me out in this example. Currently, on radio change the background is not changing.

> Note: I want to achieve this only with [ngClass] and Radio-buttons via
>   2-way binding.

Comment: it is working https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-radio-ngclass

Comment: Oh! Thanks, there was a typo. Answer, this below I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working example base on your code

template

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" [(ngModel)]="genderType">Male 
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" [(ngModel)]="genderType">Female 

<p [ngClass]="genderType">This is 3rd paragraph.</p>
```

style

```
.male{background:green;}
.female{background:violet;}
```

component

```
export class AppComponent {
  public genderType: string = 'male';
}
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-radio-ngclass)

Answer (score 1):

You could also simply evaluate classes dynamically, like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" [(ngModel)]="genderType">Male 
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" [(ngModel)]="genderType">Female 

<p class="{{genderType}}">This is 3rd paragraph.</p>
```

Angular brackets expression will evaluate your genderType variable as a string and will update it's class accordingly.